# Seeking a script that can loop ssh to a list of ips and perform useradd, home directory, creation and the user to the sudoers file

Tags: useradd

I have been looking all over for a simple way to combine various scripts to do this.  I am not the strongest at scripting but I am working on improving so go easy on me.  Any assistance here is appreciated.

I am not the author of this but I am using it as a start. I'd like to understand what the best approach to running this against a list of ips would be.  I'm most interested in simplicity and understanding if a user exists already and if it errors out.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script to add a user to Linux system
if [ $(id -u) -eq 0 ]; then
read -p "Enter username : " username
read -s -p "Enter password : " password
egrep "^$username" /etc/passwd >/dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "$username exists!"
    exit 1
else
    pass=$(perl -e 'print crypt($ARGV[0], "password")' $password)
    useradd -m -p $pass $username
    [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "User has been added to system!" || echo "Failed to add a user!"
fi
else
echo "Only root may add a user to the system"
exit 2
fi
```

Comment: Do you want to do the check for user existence on each destination host, or only on the host running the script?

Comment: On the destination.  If the user already exists I would in this use case just want to skip over them and move on the the next user.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than relying on scripts to do this, check out [ansible](https://www.ansible.com), it makes these tasks less mistake prone, and can be run multiple times without issue as it's idempotent. It is also agentless and runs over ssh.

- [vars prompt](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_prompts.html): to ask for username and passwords
- [user module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/user_module.html): creates users, home dir etc
- [group module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/group_module.html): if you want to create groups outside of the user module
- [line in file](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html): to modify sudoers, there are good examples but make sure you check out the one with the validate option.

Comment: understood, ill check into leveraging Ansible, I use it for many other items as well as chef, im not against it, was just stumped by this effort in Bash

Comment: Still working on this piece.  Got through some basics today.  Will continue to work at it and share what I come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script I just created to demonstrate how to do it.

```
 #!/usr/bin/env bash

warn() 
{
    printf '%s\n' "$@" >&2
}

die() 
{
    local st="$?"
    warn "$@"
    exit "$st"
}


anotherUser() {
    read -p "Add another user [y/n] " yn
    if [[ $yn = *[yY]* ]]; then
        checkUser
    fi
    exit        
}   
checkUser() {

while :
    do
        read -p "Enter user: " userName
        if id $userName 2>/dev/null
            then echo "User exists"
            anotherUser
        else
        read -p 'Enter pass: ' passWord
            adduser "$userName"
            echo "$passWord" | passwd "$userName" --stdin
            printf "User %s has been added\n" "$userName"
            exit
        fi  
    done
}

if (( EUID == 0 )); then
    checkUser
else
    die "You must be root"
fi
```

Make sure to copy the script on remote servers and execute it as follow

`ssh -t root@remoteserver 'bash accountScript'`

Comment: Took me a bit to get back and report that this worked great for an interactive  script.  Very grateful so thanks.  I will continue to expand on this.